# Как сделать, чтобы EditText не увеличивался по сторонам?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Как сделать, чтобы `EditText` не увеличивался **в стороны**, когда в него вводят текст?

---

Код разметки (`EditText'ы` в первых двух `LinearLayout'ах`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.45"
            android:text="@string/id_sender"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="17dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext_sender"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.55"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:lines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="17dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.45"
            android:text="@string/id_recipient"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="17dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext_recipient"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.55"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:lines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="17dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="@string/login" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_start"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/start_forwarding" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_stop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/stop_forwarding" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Жестко задать размеры поля, не?

Comment: @IvanVovk, я задал в `weight`, но он все равно разрастается, "выдавливая" `TextView`.

Comment: Попробуйте задать width:)

Comment: @IvanVovk, низя :)).

Comment: может тогда считать количество символов, которые можно ввести в текстовое поле

Comment: @IvanVovk, не прокатит. Минимально нужное количество символов вытеснит `TextView`.

Comment: Покажи код xml файла в котором текст эдит объявлен

Comment: @IvanDembicki, добавил.

Comment: @bukashka101, добавил ответ, проверил, все работает.

Comment: @IvanDembicki, спасибо! :D

Comment: @bukashka101, Не за что =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`android:layout_width="wrap_content"` нужно поменять на `android:layout_width="0dp"`

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext_sender"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.55"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:lines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="17dp" />
```